# Is it possible to see how close you are to getting the next heart?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm trying to befriend a villager up to a specific amount of hearts. I know that I need one more heart, but I want to know how many more gifts it will take. Is there a numeric value or a progress bar of some sort that I can check?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately there is no functionality for this in the base game.

Although, if you're willing to use mods you can use the [Lookup Anything Mod](http://www.nexusmods.com/stardewvalley/mods/541/?tab=1&navtag=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nexusmods.com%2Fstardewvalley%2Fajax%2Fmoddescription%2F%3Fid%3D541%26preview%3D&pUp=1) which when hovering over a person and pressing F1 will show you how much points you need for the next heart.

This does require [SMAPI](https://github.com/cjsu/SMAPI) to be used.